# start ordered list with number 2

Tags: number

How do I start an ordered list inside a new text block with the number 2 (or any number not 1).
I need this trick when a long ordered list is broken up by multiple image blocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`start` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#attr-start) to control the start number of an ordered list:

```html
<ol start="2">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Depending on your markup and specific requirements, you can also use a [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters), though it is a bit more involved and not as accessible by default.